# How to store an Enum ADT in Persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

How do you store an enum in Persistent?

Say you have a
data State = Ready | Unready | Error

How do you store this in a Persistent database?

Answer (score 7):

This is very simple using `derivePersistentField`, as the [Yesod docs](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/docs/Persistent-entity-syntax.md#sum-types) show.  For your case, you could do something like this

```
-- State.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module State where

import Database.Persist.TH
import Prelude

data State = Ready | Unready | Error
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
derivePersistField "State"
```

You can then import this and use it in your model as:

```
-- Model.hs
import State

SomethingSomething
    state State
```

Comment: Important note extracted from git "Note: If you created a new module, make sure add it to the exposed-modules section of your Cabal file.
"

Comment: Another note: due to the “stage restriction”, this definition *has* to be in a separate module from Models.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here for an example: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#sum-types